# Missing Auth Tokens section in Developer Settings

Tags: sentry

In Sentry Cloud there is "Auth Tokens" section available under "Developer Settings". In my self-hosted instance it's not. Is it by design or I am missing something during the configuration/installation?

I've double checked organisation settings and permissions in both instances, docs and help sections and I didn't find anything that could explain this situation.